# How to solve this problem with canberra-gtk-module running this game?

Tags: apt

It seems like i need to move paths around, but i don't know what do do exactly. looked at other people here who had the same problem and i've installed all the packages (i guess).

```
leo@leo:~/Public/Tesla Sim Linux - light$ ./Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86 
Set current directory to /home/leo/Public/Tesla Sim Linux - light
Found path: /home/leo/Public/Tesla Sim Linux - light/Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86
Mono path[0] = '/home/leo/Public/Tesla Sim Linux - light/Tesla-Sim-Linux_Data/Managed'
Mono config path = '/home/leo/Public/Tesla Sim Linux - light/Tesla-Sim-Linux_Data/Mono/etc'
Preloaded 'ScreenSelector.so'
Logging to /home/leo/.config/unity3d/Habrador/Tesla Simulator/Player.log

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.787: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.787: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.788: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.819: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.819: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.819: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.820: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.820: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.820: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.820: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.820: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.821: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.821: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.821: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.821: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.821: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.821: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.822: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.822: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.822: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.822: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.822: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.823: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(Tesla-Sim-Linux.x86:12120): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:10:05.823: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
Gtk-Message: 12:10:05.824: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
leo@leo:~/Public/Tesla Sim Linux - light$
```

But i already installed canberra-gtk-module and other things as well, here is proof

```
leo@leo:~$ sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
[sudo] password for leo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libcanberra-gtk3-module is already the newest version (0.30-7ubuntu2).
libcanberra-gtk-module is already the newest version (0.30-7ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

The filepath has x86 in the name, so you have to install 32-bit versions of the packages

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra-gtk3-module:i386   gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```

along with other packages like

```
sudo apt-get install adwaita-icon-theme
```